# Speex for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, speex

How do I use speex for Blackberry application ?

Is there any sample code available to refer ?

Answer (score 1):

A common set of BlackBerry supported audio formats are AAC, AMR, AU, GSM, MP3, WAV, WMA.
Unfortunatly no [audio/x-speex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speex) support.

See
[BB KB DB-00497 - What Is - Supported audio formats](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800332/1089414/What_Is_-_Supported_audio_formats.html?nodeid=1187763)
[BB KB KB05482 - Media types supported on the BlackBerry smartphone](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB05482&sliceId=SAL_Public&dialogID=50352857&stateId=0%200%2024834172)

Comment: what if I record audio in default format and then convert it to speex format?
Will this work on Blackberry?

Comment: well, if you can do this in J2ME by your own, there should be no troubles. although there is a page for related project (http://sourceforge.net/projects/j2mespeex/) it's not active yet.

Comment: Im not getting how do I workout speex in Blackberry...
Please help.

Comment: as I said, you'll have to implement it yourself, as long as no J2ME or BB library can be found...

Comment: Hmmm,trying to work out on my own now...will definiely like to post wht conclusions I draw from speex implementation :)
Thanks,Coldice.

Comment: Hi  imMobile, I'm trying the same thing , Do you find any work around for this ?